# C : Valgring warns about "Invalid write/read of size 8" & close syscall

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm testing my binary with valgrind, and I get many warnings like this one :

```
Invalid write of size 8
==7414==    at 0x402AAE: list_create_node (simple_list.c:53)
==7414==    by 0x40267E: list_add_elem_at_back (simple_list2.c:21)
==7414==    by 0x401C8A: parse (is_valid2.c:31)
==7414==    by 0x40246C: ko_parse (main.c:53)
==7414==    by 0x40255B: ko (main.c:74)
==7414==    by 0x4025E1: main (main.c:96)
==7414==  Address 0x6fe52d8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==7414==    at 0x4C277AB: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7414==    by 0x402A75: list_create_node (simple_list.c:50)
==7414==    by 0x40267E: list_add_elem_at_back (simple_list2.c:21)
==7414==    by 0x401C8A: parse (is_valid2.c:31)
==7414==    by 0x40246C: ko_parse (main.c:53)
==7414==    by 0x40255B: ko (main.c:74)
==7414==    by 0x4025E1: main (main.c:96)
```

I saw that there are many posts about that but I can't find where's the problem in my code :

```
t_node          *list_create_node(char *element)
{
  t_node        *node;

  if ((node = malloc(sizeof(t_node *))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  if ((node->value = strdup(element)))
    node->next = NULL; //// line 53 from simple_list.c
  return (node);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Valgrind also warns about reading...And that :

```
==7415== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1024 in syscall close()
```

I have a close() smewhere in my code, but even when I comment it, the message keeps being displayed. Why is that?

Comment: Bad: `malloc(sizeof(t_node *)`  Good: `malloc(sizeof(t_node)`

Comment: @FoggyDay Better: `malloc(sizeof *node)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to `malloc` the size of what your pointer is pointing to, not the size of the pointer itself. I.e: change

```
(node = malloc(sizeof(t_node *)))
```

to

```
(node = malloc(sizeof(t_node)))
```

or better yet:

```
(node = malloc(sizeof *node))
```

Then you don't have to change the `malloc`-call if you decide to change the type of `node`.

Comment: Thx you're right, all error messages vanished! Btw what's the difference between `(node = malloc(sizeof(t_node)))` & `(node = malloc(sizeof *node))`? Is the second option more "optimized"?

Comment: Nothing to do with optimization, by using `node = malloc(sizeof *node)` you don't have to repeat the type. This is good, since if you change the type of `node` you don't have to change all corresponding malloc calls, which helps you avoid bugs when refactoring.

Comment: Okay @danvari, thank you :)
I just noticed that I still have the "invalid file descriptor" message

Comment: @Amina your code doesn't show any file-descriptors or `close`-calls. I suggest you ask another question dedicated to that issue, with the relevant code in it. Otherwise this question would become to broad-topiced.